# mysql query to compare two columns values which are stored as comma separated

Tags: mysql

I want to compare column  'userid' with 'update_userid' and get  values which are not matched and don't retrieve duplicate values i.e matched values should not come

```
id  department  userid   update_userid

1    3           1,2,3       1,2
```

Comment: Do NOT store comma separated data into the db. This is a really bad approach which will lead to a lot of issues. Think about [normalization](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php)

Comment: Have you made any attempt at writing this query?

Comment: @RiggsFolly no I don't know how to start this

Comment: @Anonymous: If you are *required* to use the wrong design then you're going to have to put in considerable effort to account for that design.  You don't have IDs, you have strings.  And you have entirely custom logic for how to "compare" those strings.  Time to start looking into the variety of string manipulation tools available in MySQL and start building your complex comparison logic: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html